# Laravel model mutator not working when using attach to save on pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model, eloquent

I have a model mutator on my pivot table like so:

When I save to it like this:

```
$account_transaction->subcategories()->attach($water_subcategory->id, ['amount'=>56]);
```

The database shows 56, instead of 5600.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SubcategoryTransaction extends Model
{
protected $table = 'subcategory_transaction';
protected $fillable = ['amount'];

public function getAmountAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value) {
        $value = $value / 100;
        return $value;
    }
    return null;
}

public function setAmountAttribute($value)
{
    $value = $value * 100;
    dd($value);
    $this->attributes['amount'] = $value;
}
}
```

I was able to create a Trait with a method that gets called on the amount before attaching.

Now when I retrieve these data like this:

```
 return $this_month_transactions = AccountTransaction::where('account_id', $account_id) 
->whereBetween('date', [ $first_of_month_date->format('Y-m-d'), $last_of_month_date->format('Y-m-d'), ]) 
->with('entity','subcategories') 
->get();
```

I need to run the round($value/100,2) on each amount:

`"subcategories": [
   {
   "id": 61,
   "once_monthly": 1,
   "transaction_category_id": 10,
   "name": "Rent & mortgage",
   "slug": "rent-mortgage",
   "type": "expense",
   "created_at": "2018-08-16 05:44:53",
   "updated_at": "2018-08-16 05:44:53",
   "pivot": {
   "transaction_id": 1,
   "subcategory_id": 61,
   "created_at": "2018-08-16 05:44:54",
   "updated_at": "2018-08-16 05:44:54",
   "amount": 72500
   }`
   }

I need 72500 to become 725.00

Comment: Looks like your getter and setter are converting to its original value i.e 56.
Setter is multiplying and getter is divining so returns original value.

Comment: that's the idea, but it should hit the setter just before save and the DB should show the value * 100. It isn't hitting the setter for some reason.

Comment: Yeah I did, it's not getting hit. Nothing happens.

Comment: You are trying to mutate the value that will be saved to pivot table. But mutator will only work on SubcategoryTransaction  model and will not work on pivot table

Comment: Subcategory Transaction is the pivot table.

Comment: Its impossible to use setters, will not affect them ... make the change in the controller

Comment: I really don't want to have to keep track of this in more than one place.

Comment: Laravel doesn't support what you want to do.

Comment: You can use a trait and define a method there to update your amount value. In this  way you will not have to keep track in more than one place. You can also make helper function for it,

Comment: like this? `<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

trait NumberFormatter
{
    public function getValue(float $value)
 {
  return $value = $value / 100;
 }

    public function setValue(float $value)
 {
  return $value = $value * 100;
 }
}
`

Comment: `  $account_transaction->subcategories()->attach($auto_loan_subcategory->id, ['amount'=>$this->setValue(200)]);
`

Comment: Exaclty. But make name of the function more specific

Comment: HOw to run it on entire collection tho?

Comment: like here, ```        return $this_month_transactions = AccountTransaction::where('account_id', $account_id)
                ->whereBetween('date', [
            $first_of_month_date->format('Y-m-d'),
                $last_of_month_date->format('Y-m-d'),
                ])
                ->with('entity','subcategories')
                ->get();``` Subcategories is the pivot data

Comment: Updated the question with the info

Comment: Do I need to run each on the whole thing before returning? `$collection->each(function ($item, $key) {
    //
});`

Comment: round the amount in your getValue() and setValue() methods in trait according to your requirements

Comment: I had to do this: `  return $this_month_transactions->each(function (&$transaction) {
   $transaction->subcategories->each(function(&$subcategory) {
    return $subcategory->pivot->amount = $this->addDecimalToAmount($subcategory->pivot->amount);
   });
  });
`

Comment: thanks for your help! i'm going to close this out.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Just FYI, as of 5.5 you can now use accessors and mutators in Pivots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're using Laravel >=5.5 you can add accessor and mutators to a pivot model.

Firstly, change your `SubcategoryTransaction` class to extend the `Pivot` class instead of the `Model` so you should end up with something like:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class SubcategoryTransaction extends Pivot {

    /**
     * Convert the amount from pence to pounds.
     *
     * @param $amount
     * @return float|int
     */
    public function getAmountAttribute($amount)
    {
        return $amount / 100;
    }

    /**
     * Set the amount attribute to pence.
     *
     * @param $amount
     */
    public function setAmountAttribute($amount)
    {
        $this->attributes['amount'] = $amount * 100;
    }
}
```

Then in your `belongsToMany` relationships chain another method on called `using()` passing it the name of your pivot model e.g.:

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subcategory::class)
        ->using(SubcategoryTransaction::class) // <-- this line
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->withPivot('amount');
}
```

Comment: You're the man Ross! Do I still need `->withPivot` on the subcategories() method?

Comment: @zeros-and-ones Yes, you will do. Sorry I didn't add it into the example.