# Bootstrap input with button in navbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a search bar in Bootstrap, but I want it to be attached to the navbar. [Here is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIkCd.png). The code for that:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

That works perfectly fine. But what if I add a button to it:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwVik.png), it gets all messed up instead of being on 1 line. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

All code for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="topnav">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topnav">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/about">About This Site</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-left"><form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;User Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That looks like a Bootstrap 3 Navbar, not Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `input-group-btn` class in Bootstrap 4. Use an [input-group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/) as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696685/search-input-with-an-icon/45696757#45696757)

```
      <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
            <div class="input-group-append">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary fa fa-search" type="submit"></button>
            </div>
      </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/B1f1zG4RWQ

Also, there is no `btn-default` or `navbar-form` in Bootstrap 4. [Refer to the docs](https://getbootstrap.com) to make sure you're using the correct markup and classes.