# Bootstrap 5 airbnb clone : Search bar as button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to create a **search bar button** like **airbnb** using **bootstrap 5** something like this :

[image]

**HTML Code :**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
        <span class="search-label">start your search</span>
        <span class="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
</button>
```

Comment: You should add some examples of code you've written to try and achieve this.
On StackOverflow you won't just get the code served to solve your issue without having put some effort into it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an input group and the border utilities. This was also [available in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696685/search-input-with-an-icon-bootstrap-4), but now `left` and `right` have change to `start` and `end`...

```
           <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg border-end-0 border border-dark rounded-pill rounded-end" type="text" value="Start your search" id="example-search-input" />
                <span class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg border-start-0 rounded-pill rounded-start" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
           </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/Dv7ynKFM6J

Also see: [Search input with an icon Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696685/search-input-with-an-icon-bootstrap-4?noredirect=1&lq=1)