# Adding close buttons / 'x' clear text icons to Bootstrap5 Form Floating and Form Control input fields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

With Bootstrap 5 I'd like to add a [close button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/close-button/) to [form floating](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/) and [form control](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/) input fields so users can easily clear text on mobile, but it's not working as expected. I'm after a simple 'x' on the right end that'll show after text input, [as shown in the search field in this example](https://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=19799).

Minimal reproduction of examples from docs with the close button I expected to work inserted:

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" disabled aria-label="Close"></button>
  <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" disabled aria-label="Close"></button>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I might be doing something stupid, but I can't find any examples on this for Bootstrap 5, so please forgive the dumb question.

Comment: I guess you might need to add that manually. I don't came across any official docs from bootstrap providing that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="input-group position-relative d-inline-flex align-items-center">
            <input class="form-control " formControlName="textInput" type="text" value="">
            <i class="bi bi-search position-absolute" 
            style="
              right: 10px;
              cursor: pointer;
              z-index: 100;">
            </i>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-5-playground-forked-z65ldi?file=/index.html

Answer (score 3):

> "I'm after a simple 'x' on the right end that'll show after text
> input, as shown in the search field in this example."

The 'X' in that example is simply a search type input...

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input type="search" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
  <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
</div>
```

Or, use an input group as explained in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696685/search-input-with-an-icon-bootstrap/45696757#45696757)

```
       <div>
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput2" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control border-end-0 border" type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" id="exampleFormControlInput2">
                <span class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-white border-start-0 border" type="button">
                        <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
       </div>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/UdGUhVP31F)

Comment: This code doesn't seem to show "x" nor can I find `type="search"` anywhere in the docs. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes it does show the X when you enter text in the input. It's the standard [HTML5 search input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search).. it has nothing to do with Bootstrap

Comment: Chrome adds the x, other browsers don't. How can we enforce the x when using Bootstrap?